# File handle for lifetime of an object

Tags: python-3.x, file-handling

I am writing a log parser which parses several hundred log files and writes the stat to a single CSV file. How do I ensure that this CSV file stays open for the lifetime of the Parser Class object.

A snippet of my code so far below:

```
class LogParser():
    def __init__(self):
        self.stats_file = open('out.csv', 'a+')

    def analyze_log(self, logfile):
        with open(logfile, 'r') as f:
            # do stuff to read stats from file
            self.stats_file.write(stats)

    def __del__(self):
        self.stats_file.close()
```

What is the preferred way of cleaning up resources such as sockets, files or database connections in python?

I tried looking into context managers or context decorators to handle this use case but that seems to be applicable for lifetime of a function/method. Am I missing something here?

Comment: What is the issue with your current implementation?

Comment: I should clarify that my implementation does the job as it. But several answers I have seen in stack-overflow and other sources discourage the use of `__del__`. One such example is [this link](http://www.algorithm.co.il/blogs/programming/python-gotchas-1-__del__-is-not-the-opposite-of-__init__/). I am trying to understand if use of `__del__` is discouraged what is the preferred way of approaching this problem.

Comment: Okay, please edit your question to emphasize on that. The link you provided says that the `__del__` is called even in case of an exception, so either you can add a `try-except` block in your `__init__` or check in the destructor if file is opened using `if(not self.stats_file.closed)`

Comment: Checkout this link, it suggests using `weakref`.  https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/06/12/safely-using-destructors-in-python